# Event to fire in DTM after async API

Tags: css, tags, adobe-analytics, tms, adobe-dtm

I am new to Adobe Analytics and DTM.

On my website, an **asynchronous** API is creating a div on the page dynamically. This DIV has a special CSS class, let's say "wantedClass".

I want to create 2 rules :

- A rule that fires once the DIV **appears** on the page, which i did like using **Page Load Rules** as following :

[image]

On this trigger, an **event1** is fired in Adobe Analytics.

I picked **onLoad** because I read that this is the last one among the other options, and I want to make sure that the API async finished creating the DIV so this event would be fired.

- A rule that fires once the DIV is **clicked**, which I did using **Event Based Rules** as following :

[image]

On this trigger, an **event2** is fired.

---

What's happening when I test is :

1. Page loads, **no event1 is fired**
2. DIV clicked, **no event2 is fired**, BUT event1 is fired.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated;

Answer (score 0):

**1. Page loads, no event1 is fired**

Async calls by their nature can happen after DOM Ready or window load (onLoad), so `onLoad` is not guaranteed to trigger after some API (async) ajax call is made and returns something.

Ideally, you should trigger something in the API's ajax success callback function. You can create and trigger a **Custom Event** which DTM can listen for in an **Event Based Rule**. Note: If you go this route, make sure you create/trigger on `document.body` or a decendant; DTM will not listen for custom events on `document` itself. Also, since I see you using jQuery syntax in your screenshot, if you go this route, also note that jQuery custom event functionality is NOT the same as native javascript custom events. So for example if you do `$( document.body ).trigger( "someEvent" )`, this does NOT push to something listening to

`document.body.addEventListener('someEvent', function (e) { /* ... */ }, false);`

DTM uses the above to listen for custom events. So TL;DR - don't use jQuery syntax to create or broadcast custom events if you intend on using DTM's built-in custom event listener.

Alternatively, within the API's ajax callback function, you can just do `_satellite.track('dc_rule_value_here');` and create a **Direct Call** rule with 'dc_rule_value_here' as the string condition.

If you cannot add something to the API ajax callback function, the next best thing is to create a **Data Element** of **Custom Code** type, with the code you have in your screenshot condition (returning true or false if `.wantedClass` is found). Then, create an **Event Based Rule** of **Data Element Changed** type, with a condition reflecting what you return from the data element. This isn't ideal because this rule type works by polling the data element every 1 second for the duration of the page view. This isn't that big a deal in the grand scheme of things but it is not as efficient as other methods (and if you 0make it a practice to do this for a lot of rules, then it might become a problem). Note that you should also bake into your Data Element to only return true once, so that it doesn't keep triggering the EBR every 1s after its found (DTM does not have a native "fire only once" type config).

**2. DIV clicked, no event2 is fired, BUT event1 is fired.**

Not sure about this one. At face value, it sounds like the DTM rule itself is working, but there is a problem with the AA `s.events` being set. Could be that you simply typo'd and put `event1` into the rule, though I'm sure you checked that.. right?

Could be you have other code (e.g. code within `s.doPlugins` callback) that is overwriting it. Or maybe it's some other rule entirely that is triggering, not the one above.

May be able to help further if you provide more details on how/where you actually set the event (including other places you may be setting both events), but it but kinda sounds like something I'd have to see this in action on a page to really get to the bottom of it :/